# KineticJS Line Points as an argument

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

is there anyway to give the points of line with an array.

```
var line = new Kinetic.Line({
                points : [{
                    x : line_points_x,
                    y : line_points_y
                }],
                stroke : 'black',
                strokeWidth : 5,
                lineCap : 'round'
            });
```

I tried something but didn't work.I have 2 arrays that holds x and y points.

Comment: If you can merge your two arrays with alternating x & y positions, you can pass that as a single array. But I haven't seen a support for 2 separate arrays, but guess what... you can write your own custom draw function http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setDrawFunc

Comment: @Ani I merged tow array and it worked.Thank you very much.

Comment: Well then I'll put the comment as an answer and you can mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There are only 3 allowed structures.

`[0,1,2,3]`, `[[0,1],[2,3]]` and `[{x:0,y:1},{x:2,y:3}]`

So you have to do something like this:

```
var points = [];
for(var i=0; i<line_points_x.length; i++) {
   points.push( { x: line_points_x[i], y: line_points_y[i] } );
}

var line = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: points,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    lineCap: 'round'
});
```